# Из диапазона список значений, расположенных правее ячеек с искомым словом

Tags: excel, vba, excel-формулы

Утро доброе! Имеется таблица Excel

- Красным я отметил ячейку перед важной информацией
- Справа от красного нужная мне инфа
- Инфа хаотично разбросана

В ячейке после красной, лежит нужная инфа (на одной строке). Её нужно перенести в пустой столбец. Как вырвать соседнюю ячейку?

Пример
[image: пример]

Comment: Если цветовая заливка сделана с помощью условного форматирования, то данные можно извлечь формулой, используя условие форматирования (формула будет тяжелая в вычислениях). Если цвет проставлен вручную - только макросом. Вопрос: цветом залиты ячейки с одним словом. Если это так, зачем закрашиать? Условие для копирования - слово "Industry"

Comment: Уточните конкретно- по какому правилу Вы выделяете нужную ячейку?

Comment: задача разовая? поиск только по одному слову Industry?

Comment: @vikttur Да, заливка выполнена с помощью условного форматирования

Comment: @NovitskiyDenis нет, такие вот доки приходят каждый день и с ними нужно как то работать

Comment: @vikttur красил для удобства понимания примера

Comment: Уточните задачу. Нужно копировать данные или "вырывать"? В заголовке написано о двух ячейках, в самом вопросе - только о найденном  справа.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В указанном диапазоне ищем слово. Из значений правее ячеек со словом формируем массив. После обработки массив выгружаем на лист

```
Sub ValueOnTheRight()
Dim aRes()
Dim rRng As Range, c
Dim lCnt As Long, k As Long
Const sStr As String = "Industry"
    Set rRng = Range("C2:K250")
    lCnt = Application.CountIf(rRng, sStr)
    ReDim aRes(1 To lCnt, 1 To 1)

    For Each c In rRng
        If c.Value = sStr Then
            k = k + 1
            aRes(k, 1) = c.Offset(, 1).Value
        End If
    Next c

    Range("L2:L" & k + 1).Value = aRes
End Sub
```

Макрос разместить в общем модуле.

Эту же задачу выполняет формула

```
=ЕСЛИОШИБКА(ИНДЕКС($A$1:$L$250;
НАИМЕНЬШИЙ(
ЕСЛИ($C$2:$K$250="Industry";СТРОКА($C$2:$K$250)+СТОЛБЕЦ($C$2:$K$250)*0,001);СТРОКА(A1));
1+ПРАВБ(НАИМЕНЬШИЙ(
ЕСЛИ($C$2:$K$250="Industry";СТРОКА($C$2:$K$250)+СТОЛБЕЦ($C$2:$K$250)*0,001);СТРОКА(A1));
3));"")
```

Формула массива. Записать в ячейку, в режиме редактирования нажать *Ctrl+Shift+Enter* - формула должна заключиться в фигурные скобки. Копировать (протянуть) ячейку вниз.

Недостатки формулы:

- требует специального ввода;
- производит много вычислений, при большом количестве может вызвать подтормаживание при пересчетах;
- по строкам протягивать нужно с запасом, иначе можно не увидеть последних значений.

' ---------------------

Дополнение. Вывод результата построчно в сответствии  с найденными значениями.

```
Sub ValueOnTheRight2()
Dim aRes()
Dim rRng As Range, c
Dim lCnt As Long
Const sStr As String = "Industry"
    Set rRng = Range("C1:K250"): lCnt = rRng.Rows.Count
    ReDim aRes(1 To lCnt, 1 To 1)

    For Each c In rRng
        If c.Value = sStr Then
            aRes(c.Row, 1) = c.Offset(, 1).Value
        End If
    Next c

    Range("L1:L250").Value = aRes
End Sub
```

Если в одной строке несколько искомых значений, в результат запишется только одно. Для накопления изменить строку записи:

```
aRes(c.Row, 1) = aRes(c.Row, 1) & " " & c.Offset(, 1).Value
```

Comment: Буду очень рад. Пытался использовать но пока не получается...

Comment: Если красили для удобства, то код и дополнять нечем - макрос рабочий.  Пользователю нужно указать три момента: искомое слово в *Const sStr*, нужный диапазон ( *Range("C2:K250"))*, столбец диапазона выгрузки (*Range("L2:L" & k + 1)*). Что именно не получается? Для разнообразия добавил формулу.

Comment: копировать, желательно сразу обе ячейки и не меняя их порядок.
![Верный XHTML] (https://a.radikal.ru/a36/1807/a5/e84eadc02267.png)
Ошибка в If c.Value = sStr Then

Comment: Какой смысл в первом столбце? - Там ведь одно и то же значение. Его можно написать в отдельной ячейке. Даже так: пишете значение, запускаете код и получаете список соответствий этому значению. Для этого достаточно константу в коде заменить ссылкой на ячейку. Dim sStr As String:  sStr  = Range("L1").Value

Comment: Чот сейчас подумал, что на самом деле никакого.

Comment: Ошибка говорит о несоответствии типов данных. *sStr*- строковая переменная, *c.Value* - значение ячейки. Проверьте данные в таблице

Comment: Всё допилил, так и не понял в чем была ошибка но переделал несколько раз и заработало :) TY

Comment: @vikttur, когда я пытаюсь выполнить ваш макрос, результирующий столбец идет без пустых строк, что может быть не так?

Comment: @Андрей Солодовников, все так. Пустых строк быть не должно. Массив формируется не в соответствии со строками исходных данных: нашли нужное слово - записали значение в следующую строку массива. Если в одной строке будет найдено несколько слов, в массив они запишутся одно под другим.

Comment: @vikttur, а как нужно изменить макрос, чтобы если в строке нет слова "Industry" (как в третьей снизу строке, или посередине)  в результирующем столбце в этом месте была бы пустая ячейка?

Comment: @Андрей Солодовников, ответ дополнен